# How to re-sign an iOS Distribution Certificate when moving development teams

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store, ios-provisioning, apple-developer

An app is being passed by the owner from the team that developed it, to another team who will now take over all updates and new app creation.

The account is in the app owners name and will remain so as responsibility for the app is passed to the new team.

The account owner receives a notice that the iOS **distribution** certificate will expire in 30 days. Presuming that the owner wants to retain the ability to publish updates to the existing app, what is the best course of action here?

I am wondering if it is important who is the 'admin' member of the team currently is, and whether the admin role can this be passed on to another user. Is another user with appropriate account logins able to generate a new **distribution** certificate on their own system? The older team is still available to generate anything that is needed for the short-term future.

I believe this question is not a duplicate as it is specifically regarding swapping the development of apps between teams and how certificates factor into this process.